# При сборке проекта получаю ошибку "Could not resolve junit"

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Версия Андроид Студии 1.4. При попытке создать новый проект каждый раз появляется ошибка, связанная с зависимостями:

> Error: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration >':app:_debugUnitTestCompile'.
>
> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.

Содержимое `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Как устранить ошибку?

---

Gradle жалуется, что не может получить доступ к ресурсу
`jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom`

Я обновила все, что требовало обновления в SDK Manager, но, к сожалению, ошибка не исчезла. Я недавно обновила Android Studio и пока по этой причине не могу в ней создавать новые проекты. Вот текст `Build.Gradle` модуля моего приложения:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.prominform.fragmentanim"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),                    'proguard-rules.pro' 
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

В общем, пока просто закомментировала строчку `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` в блоке `dependencies` и все заработало.

Comment: Нужен `build.gradle` модуля (вашего приложения), а не всего проекта. Он находится в папке `/app/`

Comment: думаю вам нужно обновить *Google Repository*  до версии 22 и заодно и все прочее, что требует обновления в *SDK Manager*

Comment: Возможно вам поможет одно из [этих решений](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142899/why-cant-android-gradle-find-junit-why-isnt-it-searching-for-it-in-remote-rep). Сначала проверьте не включен ли offline-режим, потом попробуйте подключить другие репозитории